# WCF Stream doesn't unlock file after download

Tags: wcf, stream

I offer users to download files using WCF Streams. Problem is that once file is downloaded (FileStream object is created) I can't delete that file with File.Delete(), it says it is being used by someone other. At client side after download I close stream. How to fix this?

Comment: How is your service and contract defined?

Comment: At the client side, do you close/dispose the service proxy object?

Comment: Sollution is to set FileShare parameter when creating FileStream to "FileShare.Delete | FileShare.Read"

Answer (score 0):

Your solution with "FileShare.Delete | FileShare.Read" is actually a workaround (the file handle will still not be closed). I suspect you use MessageContract that contains the Stream. In that case you have to actually do slightly more work to correctly dispose the stream, see this answer [Stream as a return value in WCF - who disposes it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483320/stream-as-a-return-value-in-wcf-who-disposes-it/7828722#7828722)